# Поставить на ссылку target _blank

Tags: php, javascript

Есть сайт, на котором установлен скрипт слайдера. В нём картинки в виде ссылок, нужно сделать ссылки открывающиеся в новом окне браузера, помогите пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr_data = [
'http://pokerhome.biz/viewtopic.php?f=242&t=149'
    ];  

    var arr_id = [0];

        function random(min, max) {
            var range = max - min + 1;
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*range) + min;
        }

    function shuffle(arr) {
        var r_i;  
        var v;  
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            r_i = random(0, arr.length-1);
            v = arr[r_i];
            arr[r_i] = arr[arr.length-1];
            arr[arr.length-1] = v;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    arr_id = shuffle(arr_id);

    var content = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < arr_id.length;i++){
        content +="<div><a href='"+arr_data[arr_id[i]]+"'><img src='./images/banner/top/"+arr_id[i]+".gif'/></a></div>";
    }

     $('#rotator').append(content);


        // получаем массив блоков с нужными нам изображениями
        var banners = $("#rotator div").toArray();

        // класс с параметрами
        settings = function() {
            this.banners = banners;              // массив блоков с изображениями
            this.sum     = this.banners.length;  // количество блоков с изображениями
            this.timeIn  = 1000;                 // время для появления
            this.timeOut = 1000;                 // время для скрытия
            this.timeView= 10000;                 // тайм-аут для показа
        }

        var obj = new settings();
        if (obj.sum < 1) {
            $("#rotator").html("<p>Изображения для показа не найдены!</p>");            
        } 
        else {

            // скрываем все изображения блока #rotator
            $("#rotator div").css({
                "display":"none"
            });

            // создаем блок для показа с индикатором загрузки для эффектного начала
            $("#rotator").prepend("<div id='rotator_view'><img src='./images/load.gif'></div>");

            // немного стилей (можно указать через CSS)
            $("#rotator_view").css({
                "height" : "125px"
            });
            $("#rotator_view img").css({
                "display" : "block",
                "margin" : "22.5px auto",
                "text-align" : "center"
            });

            // запускаем функцию показа
            view (0);
        }

        function view (num){
            // инициализируем экземпляр класса settings()
            var obj = new settings();
            // если показали все изображения, показываем их снова
            if (num >= obj.sum) num = 0;

            var interval = setInterval (function(){
                // очистка блока показа
                $("#rotator_view *").remove();

                // копия изображения в блок показа
                $(obj.banners[num]).clone().prependTo("#rotator_view");

                // показ изображения
                $("#rotator_view div").fadeIn(obj.timeIn);

                clearInterval(interval);
                num++;
            },obj.timeIn);

            // скрытие изображения
            $("#rotator_view div").fadeOut(obj.timeOut);

            // снова запускаем сами себя если изображений больше одного 
            if (obj.sum > 1) setTimeout(function(){view(num)},obj.timeIn+obj.timeOut+obj.timeView);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Прочитайте про target _blank и что можно сделать с его применением https://habrahabr.ru/post/282880/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить `html` ссылки в коде:

```
...
for(var i = 0; i < arr_id.length;i++){
        content +="<div><a href='"+arr_data[arr_id[i]]+"' target='_blank'><img src='./images/banner/top/"+arr_id[i]+".gif'/></a></div>";
}
...
```